# CSS3 Cascading Menu not working in Chrome

Tags: css

We have a website [fabulouslanzarote.com](https://www.fabulouslanzarote.com/) that has a navigation menu implemented using CSS3.  The 'The Resort' and 'The Community' menu options have 
 sub-menus.

Recently it has been reported that these sub-menus are not accessible in Chrome.  They appear when the top-level link is hovered, but disappear when you attempt to click one of the links.

We have not updated the site in a couple of months and they had been working following the last deployment, so maybe this is the result of an update to Chrome?  The menus work fine in Firefox and Edge.

Does anyone know what is preventing the sub-menus from working properly in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Johannes is correct.  The menu has a gap where, as you move your cursor over it, it loses the hover state.  Try adding a transparent pseudo element on the `ul.drop` to fill the gap and keep the hover state as the cursor moves.

```
ul.drop:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 27px;
}
```

*Disclaimer: While I don't usually recommend using hardcoded values, your menu already leverages them.  That's why I chose `27px`.  It fit based on the other hardcoded values.*

Answer (score 2):

I think they are just a little bit to far below the main menu: When you move the mouse rather slowly (and not exactly in the middle), you loose the "hover" state and the submenu disappears.

I'd move them up a bit and make that arrow on top a little bit smaller to avoid that situation.